# Sum and collapse two rows in pandas if two values are equal (order does not matter)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am analyzing a dataset that has an Origin ID (Column A), a Destination ID (Column B), and how many trips have happened between them (Column Count). Now I want to sum the A-B trips with the B-A trips. This sum is the total number of trips between A and B.

Here is how my data looks like (it is not necessarily ordered in the same way):

```
    In [1]: group_station = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 100], [2, 1, 200], [4, 6, 5] , [6, 4, 10], [1, 4, 70]], columns=['A', 'B', 'Count'])
    Out[2]: 
       A  B Count
    0  1  2 100
    1  2  1 200
    2  4  6 5
    3  6  4 10
    4  1  4 70
```

And I want the following output:

```
       A  B C
    0  1  2 300
    1  4  6 15
    4  1  4 70
```

I have tried groupby and setting the index to both variables with no success. Right now I am doing a very inefficient double loop, that is too slow for the size of my dataset.

If it helps this is the code for the double loop (I removed some efficiency modifications to make it more clear):

```
# group_station is the dataframe
collapsed_group_station = np.zeros(len(group_station), 3))
for i, row in enumerate(group_station.iterrows()):
    start_id = row[0][0]
    end_id = row[0][1]
    count = row[1][0]

    for check_row in group_station.iterrows():
        check_start_id = check_row[0][0]
        check_end_id = check_row[0][1]
        check_time = check_row[1][0]

        if start_id == check_end_id and end_id == check_start_id:
            new_group_station[i][0] = start_id
            new_group_station[i][1] = end_id
            new_group_station[i][2] = time + check_time
            break
```

I have ideas of how to make this code more efficient, but I wanted to know if there is a way of doing it without looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `np.sort` with `groupby.sum()`

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
group_station[['A','B']]=np.sort(group_station[['A','B']],axis=1)
group_station.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).Count.sum()
Out[175]: 
   A  B  Count
0  1  2    300
1  1  4     70
2  4  6     15
```

Comment: This is very nice. Any way to get pd to sort a dataframe with axis=1? It was what I was trying to do for this question (your `np.sort` bypasses it nicely).

Comment: @AmiTavory base on my knowledge I can only come with a solution by 
 passing apply `df[['A','B']]=df[['A','B']].apply(sorted,axis=1)`

Comment: W.o. `apply`, I tried to sort `df.T` but it was unhappy with the `by` parameter. In any case, nice answer.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. I don't how I did not think this before ;)

Comment: @FernandoIrarrázavalG yw :-) happy coding